# lockCanvas and synchronization in Android

Tags: android, graphics

```
@Override
   public void run()
   {
     Canvas canvas =  null; // used for drawing               {
     while  (threadIsRunning)
     {
        try
        {
         canvas = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas(null);  // line 1                               

           synchronized(surfaceHolder)             // line 2

                { //do something .....

                }

           }
        }
      }
```

According to many post and blogs `lockCanvas` will make a lock on canvas so that multiple access to canvas is not possible and `synchronized block` is used so that no other thread 
draw on canvas ..

Ques is if other thread is prevented from having a canvas by lock canvas by forcing it to wait .
**Then what is need of synchronized block as thread cannot reach this block as it is blocked**

Comment: Documentation of this method never talks about threads. `lockCanvas()` Only prevents `SurfaceView` from altering or destroying `SurfaceHolder`.

Answer (score -1):

I think, if `lockCanvas` cannot obtain lock it will just return `null` and execution will continue.