# Do I really need to synchronize on SurfaceHolder in a rendering loop of a live wallpaper

Tags: android, performance, live-wallpaper

I'm implementing a rendering loop for my live wallpaper in Android. All of the examples I found on the Internet contain a rendering loop like this:

```
public void run() {
    while (mRunning) {
        Canvas c = null;
        try {
            c = mSurfaceHolder.lockCanvas(null);
            synchronized (mSurfaceHolder) {
                doUpdate();
                doDraw(c);
            }
        } finally {
            if (c != null) {
                mSurfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Do I really need to synchronize on `mSurfaceHolder` object in a Live Wallpaper?

The question like this has been discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18961322/synchronization-in-android-game-loop) earlier, but no exact answer has been given. Also the answer by `Jason Nichols` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17639258/lockcanvas-and-synchronization-in-android) states:

> I don't understand why your synchronizing in your rendering loop. This is bad form as it may lock up your rendering thread, causing the app to appear to freeze if it can't acquire the lock immediately for any reason. It also takes time to get acquire the lock.
>
> If you've got your data organized in such a way that you need to get a lock in your rendering thread, you need to refactor your design.

I am really frustrated!

#### Update

Do I generally need any synchronization in a rendering loop? How much will it affect the rendering loop performance?

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to synchronize on `mSurfaceHolder`. This code was probably taken from Lunar Lander example from SDK and changed so many times over the web that it lost its context. `SurfaceHolder` had been chosen as the object that provides the intrinsic lock, but as well, any other object could be used.

Comment: Thanks for an­sw­er­ing my ques­tion in de­tail! Do I generally need to synchronize in a rendering loop?

Comment: If you are using two separate threads there must be some sort of synchronization. I see that you are worried about performance. First, do what you want to do and see if you really have problem with performance. If you are worried about "synchronized", check GLSurfaceView source code - it has a render loop (guardedRun()) - see how it is written.

Answer (score 1):

Actually this is quite simple. In most of the examples where synchronize is used, it is because there is a chance that `doUpdate()` and `doDraw()` methods would be accessed from more than one thread(Main thread and some helper thread).

However, if you can ensure that those methods will only be accessed from same thread, than there is no need to use synchronize at all.

An easy implementation (and best for performance) would be using a Handler like this:

```
Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
```

This will bind the handler to the main thread, and all the actions will be only on the main thread.

So use synchronize when you truly want to synchronize something.